# Отмена Retrofit Request. Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, coroutine

К примеру, выполняется какой-либо запрос на сервер с помощью Retrofit 2 и Coroutines. В это время (время выполнения запроса), пользователь смещается на предыдущий фрагмент. С помощью чего можно отменить запрос, который был запущен с помощью Retrofit? В какую сторону копать?

Или же, пользователь скрыл приложение, каким образом можно продолжить выполнение запроса и всего того, что он должен выполнить? Что для этого необходимо?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтоб использовать корутины вы создаете объект `CoroutineScope`. Что-то вроде такого

```
private val parentJob: Job = Job() 
private val backgroundScope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(parentJob + Dispatchers.IO)
```

и потом запускаете:

```
backgroundScope.launch {
        // some action
    }
```

Если пользователь к примеру покинул экран и вам больше не нужно выполнять это действие то достаточно всего-лишь вызвать метод `cancel()` на вашем `scope`.

```
 backgroundScope.cancel()
```

Так же вы можете вызвать метод `cancel()` и на самом объекте `Job` тем самым завершив все `CoroutineScope` которые были созданы внутри объекта `Job`
Посмотрите [эту лекцию по корутинам](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngGI-zVJceo). Не пожалеете.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Видео действительно очень информативное и полезное.

Comment: пожалуйста=))  .